# Cannot Implement RewardedVideoAdListener

Tags: java, android-studio, abstract-class, ads, rewardedvideoad

I am currently creating a game and my GamePanel class extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

To also implement RewardedVideoAdListener, I would need my GamePanel class to be abstract, which then gives me the following error:

> error: GamePanel is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Is there any method of working around this?

Comment: Why does your GamePanel need to be abstract?

Comment: It would need to be abstract to implement both SurfaceHolder.Callback and RewardedVideoAdListener